# How to test an endpoint that has a re-direct?

Tags: servicestack

I have the following endpoint I use to confirm email addresses:

```cs
public ConfirmEmailResponse Get(ConfirmEmail req)
{
    var cacheItem = Cache.Get<ConfirmEmailCacheItem>(req.Token);
    if (cacheItem == null)
    {
        base.Response.AddHeader("Location", $"/mail-confirm??confirmed=false");
        base.Response.StatusCode = 302;
        return ConfirmEmailResponse.GetExpiredResponse();
    }

    var domain = _settings.GetRequiredString("site:frontend");

    var user = (IUserAuth)Db.LoadSingleById<UserAuthCustom>(cacheItem.UserId);

    user.UpdateToVerified(_authRepository);

    Cache.Remove(req.Token);
    Cache.Remove($"email-confirm:{user.Id}");

    base.Response.AddHeader("Location", $"/mail-confirm?confirmed=true");
    base.Response.StatusCode = 302;

    return new ConfirmEmailResponse
    {
        Success = true,
        PublicMessage = "Email has been confirmed"
    };
}
```

I am trying to write a test for this process but the re-direction is causing issues in the AppHost I built for testing.

If I try this:

```cs
var client = CreateClient();

var email = (EmailSenderMock)AppHost.Resolve<IEmailSender>();
var token = email.EmailMessages.First().ContentValues["token"];

var confirm = new ConfirmEmail{ Token = token };

var confirmResponse = client.Get(confirm);
```

Then SS generates a "Not Found" exception.  I have to remove the header and status code in order to get the response.

I tried instead to test service directly without the client like so:

```cs
var email = (EmailSenderMock)AppHost.Resolve<IEmailSender>();
var confirmService = AppHost.Resolve<UserEmailServices>();
var token = email.EmailMessages.First().ContentValues["token"];

var confirm = new ConfirmEmail{ Token = token };

confirmResponse = confirmService.Get(confirm)
```

But now `base.Request` is null so it throws exception.

What is right way to test a service containing a re-direct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the redirect is for browsers, your test should be impersonating one by requesting for a HTML response.

As this isn't a normal Service Client request you should instead use a general HTTP Client like [HTTP Utils](https://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils), e.g:

```
var url = baseUrl.CombineWith(new ConfirmEmail { Token = token }.ToGetUrl());
var body = url.GetStringFromUrl(accept: MimeTypes.Html,
    requestFilter: req => req.AllowAutoRedirect = false,
    responseFilter: res =>
    {
        Assert.That(res.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.Redirect));
        Assert.That(res.Headers[HttpHeaders.Location],
            Is.EqualTo(...));
    });
```

Comment: Thanks.  This doesn't seem to work when returning status code is 302 but doing it this way I get a WebException thrown that contains the response object I can read from which is fine.  Is it meant to throw exception for all codes other than 200?